# Notification icon size different by using Notification class and NotificatioinCompat.Builder class

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I am working on an Android application. I had two modules .

1. Uploading files
2. Downloading files

In Uploading files I have used Notification class to show the notification.

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_logo,
            "Show On The Cloud", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

In Downloading files I have used NotificationCompat.Builder class.

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
    .setContentTitle(showname)
    .setContentText("Downloading..."/*+" Network Signal Strength :"+getNetworkSignalStrength()*/)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setProgress(100, R.id.progressBar1, true)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo)
    .build();
```

**My Query :**

I am using the same drawable for notification icon. But I have been seen the different sized icon in Actionbar.

Is there any possible way to have same size icon by using both classes in different scenariois?

**Note :**
My project's midSdkVersion = 11

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set the icon dimension at loewr dimension you see in one fo the both scenarios